# Create edit link for google drive files in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-sheets, google-drive-api

Im using the 'google_drive' gem for ruby. I can create an list google drive files in ruby. Is there a way to set the permissions to {type: 'anyone', role: 'writer'} and create a link in ruby to view or edit the google drive files i created?

Thanks, Andreas

Answer (score 3):

### Use [GoogleDrive::File#human_url](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/google_drive/1.0.5/GoogleDrive%2FFile:human_url)

You did not specify how exactly you created your file(s), but each instance of a [file](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/google_drive/1.0.5/GoogleDrive/File) has a `#human_url` - that is the link to the file that allows you to view or edit the file in a web browser.

Sample:

```ruby
session = GoogleDrive::Session.from_config("config.json")
session.upload_from_file("/path/to/hello.txt", "hello.txt", convert: false)
file_url = session.file_by_title("hello.txt").human_url
```

UPDATE

For setting permission, use the method [#create_permission(file_id, permission_object)](https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-api-client/latest/Google/Apis/DriveV3/DriveService.html#create_permission-instance_method) specifying the [permission object](https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-api-client/latest/Google/Apis/DriveV3/Permission.html).

Sample:

```ruby
permission = {type: "user", role: "writer", email_address: "user's email"}
session.drive_service.create_permission(current_user.fileId, permission)
```

whereby the file id can be retrieved similar to the file URL, with [#resource_id](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/google_drive/1.0.5/GoogleDrive/File#resource_id-instance_method) .

Comment: Thanks, this is very close to what I am looking for. I would just like to set the permissions to {type: 'anyone', role: 'writer'} beforehand.

Comment: How are you currently setting those permissions (from your quesiton I understand that you already created a file with the necessary permissions and only miss the retrieving url part)? Seeing your code would be helpful!

Comment: I don't set any permissions yet. My goal is to generate the files via the API and to provide the user with a link to edit the document directly. But you are absolutely right, I have to update my question.

Comment: I updated my question to show you how to set permissions. Whereby, as a general rule it should be one question per port on stackoverflow :-)